# Add space before and after a number

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to add a space before and after any number in a string.
For example, if I have JS35BX54NV33, I will get JS 35 BX 54 NV 33

I'm using this:

```
preg_replace("/(\\d)([a-z])/i", "$1 $2", $mystring)
```

But it only add space AFTER each number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find the zero-width positions where you wish to inject spaces using lookarounds.  No capture groups are necessary.

- `\d` matches a numeric character.
- `\D` matches a non-numeric character.
- `(?<=...)` looks behind.
- `(?=...)` looks ahead.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Wdvtv))

```
$mystring = 'JS35BX54NV33';
var_export(preg_replace('/(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\D)/', ' ', $mystring));
```

Output:

```
'JS 35 BX 54 NV 33'
```

`var_export()` is used to reveal that there are no leading or trailing spaces generated.

**Actually**, a more efficient pattern is `/\D+\K(?=\d)|\d+\K(?=\D)/` which avoids costly lookbehinds and instead uses greedy quantifiers.  This new pattern requires just 47 steps on the sample string versus 135 steps from my earlier pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try with,

```
<?php

$re = '/(\d+)/m';
$str = 'JS35BX54NV33';
$subst = ' $1 ';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
?>
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/N6rSK.

**REGEX** https://regex101.com/r/buz2AA/1

Comment: This will add extra spaces at the beginning and end of the string if it starts or finishes with a number.

Comment: Why make a mess and then clean it up in two steps?

Comment: Please explain why you are using the `m` pattern modifier and why you are using a capture group (both unnecessarily).

Comment: @mickmackusa agreed with yiou sir, the `m` flag is unnecessary here

Comment: @nick don’t see the requirements inside the question say that this wasn’t the desired result though anywhere … actually, rather the opposite, if you take it literally.

Comment: @CBroe agreed, if you take it literally, it would imply that. I was really just pointing out that fact.